# Wrapping pre-made elements using GWT?

Tags: gwt

I've been working with GWT for awhile, I can't find a way to integrate it with a preexisting website which is a real downer. My page content is already generated for me using jsp, like:

```
<div id='A'></div>
<div id='B'></div>
etc.
```

there is no way for me to do something like this though:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

    SimplePanel spA = new SimplePanel( 
      Document.getElementById("A"));
    spA.add(new Label("hello"));


    SimplePanel spB = new SimplePanel( 
      Document.getElementById("B"));
    spB.setWidth("200px");

    etc ..
}
```

seems like there's no way to just wrap a pre-existing element. Is this true, or am I missing how to do this? I need be able to wrap a bunch of elements like this, to manipulate them later on. I see TextBox, Button, a few other classes have wrap() methods, however nothing like that exists for  elements,

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to wrap existing DOM elements, like `Label`'s [`wrap()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Label.html#wrap(com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element)) method.  For example:

```
Label label = Label.wrap(DOM.getElementById("A"));
label.setText("Foo!");
```

Other GWT classes can wrap DOM elements too, like `Button`, and `CheckBox` using its constructor.

Comment: Right wrap() methods exist for Label, Button, CheckBox, but FlowPanel and SimplePanel, do not have a wrap() method. Do you know of a way to support this? I basically just want to wrap a <div>.

Comment: You can do this with `RootPanel.get(...)` too.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try to work with that, probably have a follow-up issue with this will open as a new Q, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use HTMLPanel:

```
class MyPanel extends HTMLPanel {
    private SimplePanel a = new SimplePanel();
    private SimplePanel b = new SimplePanel();

    public MyPanel() {
        super("<div id="a"></div><div id="b"></div>);
        addAndReplaceElement(a, "a");
        addAndReplaceElement(b, "b");
    }
}
```